# Using encrypt() in Laravel Migrations

Tags: laravel

Can I encrypt a column in Laravel Migrations?

For example:

```
$table->encrypt('this_field')
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To encrypt specific columns in your Laravel model, you can use the $casts property. Navigate to your model and add the columns you want to encrypt as follows. Laravel will automatically handle the encryption for you.

```
protected $casts = [
    'email' => 'encrypted',
    'phone' => 'encrypted',
    'salary' => 'encrypted'
];
```

This configuration informs Laravel that the 'email', 'phone', and 'salary' columns should be treated as encrypted fields. Laravel will handle the encryption and decryption process transparently when you retrieve or store data using these attributes.

Answer (score 0):

you should use the `string` field and encrypt it with any algorithm in your logic.

```php
$table->string('password');


// For example UserService.php
->create([
  'password' => bcrypt('secret')
])
```